# PowerBI - Filter Table/Report based on User Selection of Slicer falls between Valid From Date & Valid To Date

Tags: powerbi

I have been trying to find an answer to my problem but to no avail, so hoping someone is able to provide some ideas / advice on if this is possible and if so, how to go about it?  I've tried various things and none have worked.

We create views within SQL and then connect to them using 'Import' from the Data Connectivity Mode when connecting to the SQL Server from within Power BI.  Within the view, we use tables that contain a 'Valid From Date' and 'Valid To Date' for each row of data, so when a change occurs a row is closed off and a new row is created.  This is so we can limit the rows of data within the table.

When trying to create a report within Power BI, we need to make it that the end user can use a data drop down list to select a date and the data within the whole of the report shows any rows that the selected date falls on or between the Valid From and Valid To dates.  We use Cards, Tables, Matrix and Charts within our reports, so all would need to reflect the date selected by the user.

I have tried various methods that I could think to get it to work but each have had limitations where it either doesn't work or only partly works.

Any help / advice on this would be really appreciated.

Many Thanks

Jon

Comment: Consider adding a small sample of rows of data or at minimum be explicit about what columns exist in your view so that we can spin up help on our PowerBIs.

Comment: Thanks @MikeG I'll try and get an example of what I'm trying to do and I'll attach it.